# function or formula for calculating 2 box side

Tags: math

I'm just new here, I wanna ask a formula to calculate getting the boxes side if inline or not.

[image]
[image]

I need a formula to know if box2 or box1 are in the same sides

Comment: So box2 has to be within the width of box1? Within the red lines?

Comment: I can't make any sense of the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, my best guess its about figuring out if two inner rects have collinear vertical sides (which is pretty trivial in cartesian coords).

Comment: @Free Consulting is right, thank you.

Comment: 2 box are moving inside the mainbox, so if both box1 and box2 has the same side either left or right the result is true.

Comment: What do you know about the boxes?  Do you have the coordinates of the corners?  Or just the centers?  Or do you just have a picture?  Free Consulting pointed out this is trivial in cartesian coordinates.  What is making the problem too difficult for you?

Comment: @Teepeemm,  Assuming box1 and box2 are moving from left or right, when both box will have same side on edge either left or right it returns true.  Assuming the mainBox is 100x100, the box1 is 50x15, box2 is 30x10.  I don't have enough to say because I think I have ask the correct way.  now please can you help like Alex B.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you need a method, that checks if two boxes (rectangles) are aligned (either left or right)? Here's a very quick solution:

```cs
public enum Side {
    Left,
    Right
}

public bool CheckIfAligned(Rect box1, Rect box2, Side side) {
    if(side == Side.Left)
        return box1.Location.X == box2.Location.X;
    else // side == Side.Right
        return box1.Location.X + box1.Width == box2.Location.X + box2.Width;
}
```

Comment: Actually 2 box are moving inside the mainbox, so if both box1 and box2 has the same side either left or right then that's the formula I'm looking for, thank you.